# Export C++ function to python using ctypes: undefined symbol

Tags: python, c++, shared-libraries, python-3.4, ctypes

Consider this file containing two similar functions:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "main\n";
}

int notmain()
{
  std::cout << "notmain\n";
}
```

I compiled this into a shared library:

```
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,code -o code.so -fPIC code.cpp
```

I wish to call these from python, for `main` this works fine:

```py
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("code.so")
libc.main()
```

Which prints `main`. However, `notmain` doesn't work:

```py
import ctypes
libc = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("code.so")
libc.notmain()
```

The output:

```py
<ipython-input-63-d6bcf8b748de> in <module>()
----> 1 libc.notmain()

/usr/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py in __getattr__(self, name)
    362         if name.startswith('__') and name.endswith('__'):
    363             raise AttributeError(name)
--> 364         func = self.__getitem__(name)
    365         setattr(self, name, func)
    366         return func

/usr/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py in __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal)
    367 
    368     def __getitem__(self, name_or_ordinal):
--> 369         func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
    370         if not isinstance(name_or_ordinal, int):
    371             func.__name__ = name_or_ordinal
```

I assume that main is 'exported' to the outside world (w.r.t. code.so) in a different way than `notmain` because `main` is a special case in the c++ specs. How can I 'export' `notmain` in the same way? Or: how can I fix the exception?

**EDIT** As suggested by @abdallahesam I added `estern "C"` to `notmain`, this did not change (or solve) the problem:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::cout << "main\n";
}

extern "C" {
  int notmain()
  {
std::cout << "notmain\n";
  }
}
```

**CORRECTION**

The suggestion did solve the problem, I just needed to restart the (i)python session. Apparently this matters :)

Comment: Interestingly, nm shows the main-function as a symbol `00000000000008a5 T main` and the notmain-function as a symbol with 'signature additions' for the typing: `00000000000008c6 T _Z7notmainv`

Comment: I was having the same problem and the only solution was restarting the python session. In my case I will need this to work without restarting the python session. Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should add **extern "C"** to your **notmain** function header to prevent c++ compiler from altering  function name.

Comment: Thank you, I tries this as denoted in the OP, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Correction: I needed to restart my ipython session for this to work.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `extern "C" ...` or `extern "C" {...}` if ... is just one statement. I tried both anyway, and it works.

Comment: Thank you anyway! This could have cost me hours to solve otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to link all libraries dynamically to the one library you want to open by **ctypes**.